# Contract calling a function in another contract : TypeError

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ganache

I have three contracts `Ignition.sol`  , `Factory.sol`, `Cookie.sol` , Ignition should call the function 'factoryStart()' in the Factory contract. newCookie() creates new `Cookie.sol` contracts depending on the passed arguments.

Parts of code has been omitted for readability.

Ignition.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Ignition {
 
 uint256 attr1;
 uint256 attr2;

 constructor(uint256 _attr1, uint256 _attr2){
   attr1 = _attr1;
   attr2 = _attr2;
 }

 // do stuff...

    function factoryStart() public {

     Factory.newCookie( attr1, attr2 );
    }

}
```

Factory.sol :

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Factory {

 uint256 attr1;
 uint256 attr2;

 constructor(uint256 _attr1, uint256 _attr2){
 attr1 = _attr1;
 attr2 = _attr2;
 }

 // do stuff...

 function newCookie() public {

 Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(attr1, attr2);
 }

}
```

Right now, I get a compilation error;
**TypeError: Cannot call function via contract type name.**

I know my solution must be wrong somehow because I need the ABI/Address of `Factory` in Ignition so that interaction can happen but I couldn't figure out how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let's start with a basic question - what do you expect (or want) `Factory.newCookie( attr1, attr2 )` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know my solution must be wrong somehow because I need the ABI/Address of `Factory` in `Ignition` so that interaction can happen but I couldn't figure out how.

No, your solution is wrong because you need to call a contract function via an **instance** of the contract, not via the name of the contract.

A given contract can have several instances of it deployed at several **different** addresses, so calling a contract function via the name of the contract makes no sense.

Technically speaking, you need to do something like this:

```
function factoryStart(Factory factory) public {
    factory.newCookie(attr1, attr2);
}
```

Alternatively, `Factory factory` can be a global variable in your contract, which you will need to initialize to point to a `Factory` instance before calling function `factoryStart`, for example:

```
Factory factory;
uint256 attr1;
uint256 attr2;

constructor(Factory _factory, uint256 _attr1, uint256 _attr2) public {
    factory = _factory;
    attr1 = _attr1;
    attr2 = _attr2;
 }
```

---

Comment: thank you @goodvibrations , I solved by declaring the contract instance a global variable.